# Twisted colouring problem

Tags: geometry, coloring

I had doubts in the following similar looking questions I came across:-

---

$Q1.$ The Cartesian plane is coloured with 2 colours. Prove that there exists 3 points of the same colour, which are the vertices of a regular,i.e, equilateral triangle.

---

$Q2.$ A sphere is coloured in 2 colours. Prove that there exists on the sphere 3 points of the same colour, which are the vertices of an equilateral triangle.

I proved the first in the following way:- First we assume that there does not exist any  equilateral triangle such that its vertices are of the same colour and proceed to get a contradiction.We select 2 points $A$ and $B$ of the same colour say blue. We can form 2 equilateral triangles with these as vertices. Since $A$ and $B$ are blue the other 2 vertices $C$ and $D$ must be of the other colour,i.e, red according to our assumption. Refer http://tube.geogebra.org/student/mg4lR6SJD for a diagram. Now using $C$ and $D$ as vertices, 2 more equilateral triangles can be made and those 2 vertices($E$ and $F$) should be blue. Now we see that the points $A,B,E$ and $F$ are of blue colour and $EA=AB=BF$. Now we form the equilateral triangle $\triangle EAJ$ and $\triangle BFH$. It can be trivially proved that $\triangle JHC$ is an equilateral triangle. Now since $E,A$ and $B,F$ are blue, $J$ and $H$ should be red but that implies that all the vertices of $\triangle JHC$ are red leading to  contradiction!! _____________________________ $\mathbf MY \space DOUBT:$ Why can't we say that when we are colouring a plane or a sphere with 2 colours, there must be a region having the same colour and however small the region may be, it always will contain an equilateral triangle? Is there anything wrong with this argument, because anyway we can't say that the vertices will be lattice points as an equilateral triangle can't have lattice points as its vertices(that would mean that the area of a rational sided equilateral triangle is also rational, but by formula we know its not).

Comment: If you are thinking about the $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane, how about choosing a coloring scheme as blue for every point $A = \{(x,y):x,y \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ that is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and red the rest of the plane (i.e., no matter how small a region you choose you will find a point of $A$ in it).

Comment: @sciona, this colouring scheme is really tough to visualise(for me), so could you explain how it doesn't contain a unicolour region??

Comment: I mean color all the points in the plane with rational co-ordinates (I mean $(x,y)$ where both $x$ and $y$ are rational numbers) blue and the remaining points red. You must be aware that between any two real numbers there is a rational number. Similarly in any closed region of the plane we will always find a rational point. There can be no unicolor region under this scheme.